# <= vs < when proving big-o notation

Tags: math, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

We just started learning big-o in class. I understand the general concept that f(x) is big-o of g(x) if there exists two constants c,k such that for all x>k |f(x)|<=c|g(x)|. I had a question whether or not it is required that we include the <= to sign or whether it is just sufficient to put the < sign?

For example:
suppose f(x)=17x+11 and we are to prove that this is O(x^2).
Then if we take c=28 and x>k=1 we know that 17x+11<=28x^2. So since we know that x will always be greater than 1 this implies that 28x^2 will always be greater than 17x+11. So, do we really need to include the equal sign (<=) or is it okay if we just write (<)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

From |*f* (*x*)| ≤ *c* |*g* (*x*)| for some real-valued *c*, it follows that |*f* (*x*)| < (*c* + *e*) |*g* (*x*)| for all *e* > 0.

From that it follows that there exists *c'* = (*c* + *e*) such that |*f* (*x*)| < *c'* |*g* (*x*)|, so you can use < instead of ≤.

More practically, if you can prove |*f* (*x*)| < *c* |*g* (*x*)|, the ≤ part follows trivially.

Comment: It's a faulty proof, since the result is false. Any function f that's infinitely often zero is O(f), but not if you replace <= with < in the definition.

Answer (score 0):

If you have shown x < y then you have also shown x <= y.  So it makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

> whether or not it is required that we include the <= sign or whether it is just sufficient to put the < sign?

There are two slightly different things you're asking here,  I think:

- If you can demonstrate a `c` and `k` such that for all `x > k`  `|f(x)| <= c|g(x)|`, then trivially you have *also* demonstrated a `c` and `k` such that for all `x > k`  `|f(x)| < c|g(x)|`. So **showing `<` is *sufficient***, but:
- As you've stated, the actual requirement for being able to say `f(x) = O(g(x))` is to find a `c` and `k` such that for all `x > k`  `|f(x)| <= c|g(x)|`. If the best we can do is find a `c` and `k` such that for all `x > k`  `|f(x)| = c|g(x)|`, then we haven't met your `<` condition, but we *have* done enough to show `f(x) = O(g(x))`. So **showing `<` is not *necessary***

Answer (score 0):

You can't replace <= with < in the definition.

Any function f that's infinitely often zero is O(f), but not if you replace <= with <.

For example, let f(x) = x if x is odd, 0 if x is even. Then f is O(f) because f(x) <= f(x) for all x. However, there's no c such that f(x) < cf(x) for all large x, because both sides are 0 for all even x.

Answer (score 0):

It is **not** ok to use `<` instead of `≤`, although it is obvious that they are -in some cases- identical, because `≤` is part of the Big-O notation definition.

On the other hand, the definition: `0 ≤ f(n) < cg(n)` belongs to a different class (the Little-o notation) which is included in the Big-O class